# when I do order on a counter_cache it returns nil objects first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

I have owns_count counter_cache on my items model. When i do

```
Items.order("owns_cache DESC")
```

, it returns me objects that are nil before other results. If I do

```
"owns_cache ASC"
```

, it is correct.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How NULLs get ordered depends on the underlying database.

For PostgreSQL, you could do this:

```
Items.order("owns_cache DESC NULLS LAST")
```

For MySQL and SQLite:

```
Items.order("COALESCE(owns_cache, 0) DESC")
```

I think MySQL sorts NULLs at the bottom of a DESC ordering though so you might not need anything special there. This COALESCE approach will also work in PostgreSQL so this would be a portable solution that should give you consistent results everywhere.

If you wanted NULLs at the bottom on an ASC sort, you'd replace the `0` with something larger than the largest `owns_cache` number.